# Is it possible to get the return value of an external function that gets data from another contracts external function?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

***Note:** This is ONLY an issue when calling external-view functions from web3js, as it doesn't create a transaction*

---

I've got 2 contracts, `A` and `B`
*(one is a storage contract, and the other is more of a logic contract)*

If `A` has a function like:

```
function getValueFor(uint8 index) external view returns(uint8) {
    return someMapping[index];
}
```

And `B` has a function like:

```
function isValid() external view returns(bool) {
    return instanceOfA.getValueFor(1) == 1;
}
```

From Mist or web3js, the return value from `A` works as expected, and when invoking `B` the default value is always returned.
*(in this case `0`)*

Can you not get the return value from a contract -> contract external/constant function call from web3js? Would this require a transaction?

## Update

See [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56369/cant-get-contract-to-contract-function-calls-working/56616#56616) on ethereum.stackexchange.

I was mostly incorrect with this working during transactions. It seemed to be working with my particular test function, though most other functions failed *(I just got lucky/unlucky with the one test function I was using)*.

The root of the issue was simply not having new having Byzantium enabled on my Geth node *(which enables new EVM features)*.

Comment: is `someMapping[1]` actually 1? If so, you will always get the same value, since your isValid() always passes the same parameter

Comment: No, just a condensed snippet, the index is dynamic.

Comment: _Moving_  this over to ethereum.stackexchange: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56271/why-does-a-non-transactional-contract-to-contract-function-fail-to-return-the-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can. A quick run in Truffle console will show it:

```
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.5.0;

contract A {
    uint256 value;

    constructor(uint256 v) public {
        value = v;
    }

    function getValue() external view returns (uint256) {
        return value;
    }
}

contract B {
    A other;

    constructor(address a) public {
        other = A(a);
    }

    function getValueFromA() external view returns (uint256) {
        return other.getValue();
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> var aContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getValue","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"v","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);

truffle(development)> var transObj = { from: web3.eth.accounts[0], data: '0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b506040516020806100ea83398101806040528101908080519060200190929190505050806000819055505060a1806100496000396000f300608060405260043610603f576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff16806320965255146044575b600080fd5b348015604f57600080fd5b506056606c565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600080549050905600a165627a7a72305820dd332a08d090a6766cf7c2e86f41abc58a31e4d1afe7cb635a0a1b755a9b81cd0029', gas: '4700000'};

truffle(development)> var a = aContract.new(35, transObj);

truffle(development)> a.getValue();
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 35 ] }

truffle(development)> var bContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getValueFromA","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}]);

truffle(development)> transObj.data = '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';

truffle(development)> b = bContract.new(a.address, transObj);

truffle(development)> b.getValueFromA();
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 35 ] }
```

Comment: I'll have to give this a try. From both Mist and web3js I can only ever get back the default value of the return type. Truffle console just uses web3js, so I'm a bit stumped as to why it's working in your example vs Mist/browser. Ideas? =S

Comment: Hard to say since there’s no info on how `someMapping` is populated.

Comment: In the actual contract _(not the above condensed snippet)_ it's populated via another function. When calling `getValueFor` from my question, it does return the value stored in the mapping. It's only when I call it from another contract, where both functions are `external`/`view` that it returns the default value.

Comment: Just tried you sample in Remix. It does work there, but it creates a transaction when calling the view functions. In web3js no transaction is created for these. _(I ran into a similar issue where `msg.sender`, or just `msg`, isn't created by web3js for non-transaction view calls)_  I'll update my question to state this is only an issue with web3js not creating a transaction for the call.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work-around/hack that gets this working outside of a transaction *(external view function call using `web3js`)*

```
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.5.0;

contract Parent {
    int value;

    function setValue(int v) public {
        value = v;
    }

    function getValue() external view returns (int) {
        return value;
    }
}

contract Child {
    Parent parent;

    function setParent(address a) public {
        parent = Parent(a);
    }

    function getValue() external view returns (int value) {
        // -- Should work
        //return parent.getValue();

        // -- Make it work
        address addr = address(parent);
        bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("getValue()"));

        assembly {
           let o := mload(0x40) // Empty storage pointer
           mstore(o,sig)        // Push function signature to memory (function signature is 4 bytes/0x04)

           let success := call(
               15000,           // Gas limit
               addr,            // To address
               0,               // No ether to transfer
               o,               // Input location ptr
               0x04,            // Input size (0)
               o,               // Store oputput over input
               0x20)            // Output size (32 bytes)

           value := mload(o)
           mstore(0x40,add(o,0x04))
        }
    }
}
```

Still seems goofy that this doesn't just work using a regular function call.
*(maybe this is a bug?)*